# How to de-link a URL from Symfony link

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a issue while trying to deference the URL from my code.  I want to get URL as:

```
www.imaginar.fr
```

Instead I am getting:

```
http://localhost/epita/web/app_dev.php/questionanswer/cat/www.imaginar.fr
```

My Twig Code is as below:

```
<tr><td> <a href="{{ entity.resource}}" target="_blank">{{ entity.resource}}</a></td></tr>
```

My controller Code fetches the resource data from the database and I am trying to open that resource in a new browser without symfony extension

```
$query1 = $em->createQuery('SELECT p.id, p.question, p.answer, r.resource, r.cover 
                            FROM EpitaEpitaBundle:questionanswer p LEFT JOIN p.resource r
                            WHERE p.id LIKE :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $id);
        $res = $query1->getResult();
```

Comment: Can you show us the content of `entity.resource` ? please

Comment: For the above question entity.resource has www.imaginar,fr as the content.

Answer (score 2):

Without the http:// prefix links will simply be appended to the current pages url.

Comment: So either the OP adds "http:" when storing the data, or in the template before {{ entity.resource }}.